# SSRS Reports with DateFormat

Tags: reporting-services

I already tried for changing the dateformat with switch case .I want to write a function for the below dateformat code and i don't want to use switch case.Please any one help me.Thanks in Advance.

```
=SWITCH(Parameters!DateFormat.Value = "dd/MM/yyyy",Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy"),
Parameters!DateFormat.Value = "MM/dd/yyyy",Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy"),
Parameters!DateFormat.Value = "yyyy/MM/dd",Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,"yyyy/MM/dd"),
true,Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switch you can write below snippet of code and I think this will work.

```html
=Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,Parameters!DateFormat.Value.ToString())
```

Let me know if you are getting some error.

Comment: it is ok for Parameters and it's not working for fields in the dataset,Please help me

Comment: Are you want a calculated field from a dataset which will use this expression?

Comment: Yes, I want a calculated field from a dataset

Comment: In that case u can do an alternative as use the parameter directly in the calculated field and inside the parameter u can have ur expression. :)